# ssh windows 7 connection refuser

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh, sshd

trying  to connect from localhost

```
  ssh <MyLogin>@localhost   - connected
```

trying to connect from another computer in my local network

```
  ssh <Mylogin>@<MyServerLocalIp>   - connected
```

trying to connect from internet

```
  ssh <Mylogin>@<InternetIp> -conection refused  (it not appears in my log file)
```

i'm check 22 port in this site  http://www.canyouseeme.org/  - 22 port is open and it appears in my log file

trying use telnet

```
  telnet InternetIp 22  - not connected
```

but when i'm trying another port

```
  telnet InternetIp 21  - connected
```

Comment: Is the InternetIp you see at "canyouseeme" the same one you're using to connect from the Internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you are behind a [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) Router.

If this is the case, what you will need to do is first ensure your machine has a static IP address. This will likely be something like 192.168.1.x. You can configure this in your router by either mapping your machines MAC address to a DHCP assigned address or just configuring you machine with a static IP and checking that that IP is not in the DHCP range.

Then you will need to configure your Router to forward inbound port connections to the local IP address of your machine. Here is an article on Wikipedia about Port Forwarding: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding

Your best bet is to download the manual for your specific Router and look up the section on port forwarding. It is often in the section about the routers Firewall.

Comment: my router already configure "virtual server"(port forwarding).And if the router was not configured, the check 22 ports from sites would be successful?

Comment: It would appear that some firewall is letting FTP connections (21) through, but blocking SSH (21). When you are trying to connect using the internet IP address, is this from the localhost machine, or from another node on the internet in a different subnet? You say that the server is a Windows 7 machine, have you checked to ensure the windows firewall isn't blocking port 22 when from remote IP addresses?

Comment: i'm trying connect from localhost  and another machine in local network. all this node use same router.